# How to compare list values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare

How to compare the values inside the `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` dictionary?

if all the values in the dictionary are the same, then do something.
else do nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on *which* values you are trying to compare and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try to use in :::http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: Please check out the [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare keys of Dictionary, then:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// something..
if (dict1.Keys.SequenceEqual(dict2.Keys)) 
{
  // your code
}
```

If you want to compare values of Dictionary, then:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// something..
var d1Keys = dict1.Keys.ToList();
var result = d1Keys
    .All(key => dict2.ContainsKey(key) && dict1[key].SequenceEqual(dict2[key]));
// result == true, if equals
```